# How do you spell Vitral - meaning saying bad inaccurate things I believe?

Tags: single-word-requests, expressions

I'm trying to find the word, which I believe is something like "Vitral", like when someone is saying bad and/or inaccurate things, such as:

> This guy has been spewing a bunch of inaccurate vitral

Am I thinking of the right term here? If so, how do you spell it - not having any luck finding it in Google.

Comment: Try *vitriol* [SE requires more characters]

Comment: @Minty I believe that is it, thanks :)

Comment: As helpful this was to the asker, I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it doesn't help anyone else at all.

Comment: @Brett, I don't think we have a lot of "haters" on our site, but one thing we do object to is personal attack. Our [Code of Conduct](https://english.stackexchange.com/conduct) is quite explicit: *no subtle put-downs or unfriendly language*. Mitch gave one reason for closure, but another was equally valid: questions that can be answered using [commonly-available references](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2573) are off-topic. You say you couldn't find it, but when I googled "define vitral", it showed *vitriol* on the first page.

Comment: @Chappo Firstly, you don't have to go looking far to find the "haters" as you put it, it's very well known fact there are a large group of people that no longer use and/or despise SE for attitudes such as what Mitch displayed (along with a wide array of other various reasons) and I believe this was partially some of the reasons that brought the recent changes of SE; secondly, now you're basically calling me a liar about not being able to find it - good job!

Comment: On hold - classic SE LOL.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The correct spelling would be *vitriol*. 
https://www.dictionary.com/browse/vitriol